# Functions returning same value even with assigned event listener to the buttons

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I have created an event listener to capture button clicks from the DOM. However, when I click to either 'Odds' and 'Evens' button it always returns 0 and when I click on the buttons with the numbers '1', '2', '3', '4' and '5' they always return 5.

With the evens listener in place I expected to capture user options by Even and Odds and then capture user numbers from 1 to 5 in order to run an Odds and Evens game.

The code I have:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
let buttons = this.getElementsByTagName("button");

    for (let button of buttons) {
        button.addEventListener("click", function () {
            if (this.getAttribute("data-type") === "btn-start") {
                startGame();
            } else if (this.getAttribute("data-type") === "btn-exit") {
                location.href = "./index.html";
                console.log('Exit');
            } else if (this.getAttribute("data-type") === "btn-odds" || this.getAttribute("data-type") === "btn-evens") {
                let userOption = this.getAttribute("data-type");
                getUserOption(userOption);
            } else {
                let userNumber = this.getAttribute("data-type");
                getUserNumber(userNumber);
            }
        })
    }

})

const instructionsContainer = document.getElementById('instructions-container');
const gameContainer = document.getElementById('game-container');

function startGame() {
console.log('Started');
instructionsContainer.classList.add('hide');
gameContainer.classList.remove('hide');
}

function getUserOption(userOption) {
console.log('User selection');
let userResult;

    if (userOption === 'btn-odds') {
        userResult = 1;
    } else if (userOption === 'btn-evens'); {
        userResult = 0;
    }
    console.log(userResult);

}

function getUserNumber(userNumber) {
console.log('User number');

    let userNumberSelected;
    
    if (userNumber === 'btn-1') {
        userNumberSelected = 1;
    } else if (userNumber === 'btn-2') {
        userNumberSelected = 2;
    } else if (userNumber === 'btn-3') {
        userNumberSelected = 3;
    } else if (userNumber === 'btn-4') {
        userNumberSelected = 4;
    } else if (userNumber === 'btn-5'); {
        userNumberSelected = 5;
    }
    console.log(userNumberSelected);

}
```